# Рисование 2D фигур с java.swing

Tags: java, swing

Планировалось, что будет окно с несколькими кнопками сверху и полем. После нажатия на кнопку на поле должна прорисовываться соответствующая геом. фигура. С панелью кнопок у меня получилось как задумано: к каждой кнопке привязал объект класса MyFigure, в наследниках которого реализуется actionListener. Однако я не могу понять, в объекте какого типа  мне все рисовать и откуда брать объект Graphics, который, как я понял обязателен для рисования.
Код для окна:

```
public class MyWindow extends JFrame
{
    MyWindow()
    {
        super("My window");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Box box = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        //перечисление используется для того, чтобы не использовать кучу case блоков
        MyEnum[] myEn = MyEnum.values();
        MyFigure myFigure;
        for(int i = 0; i < myEn.length; i++)
        {
            JButton jb = new JButton(myEn[i].name());
            myFigure = myEn[i].getFigure();
            jb.addActionListener(myFigure);
            box.add(jb);
        }
        setContentPane(box);
        //Возможно здесь должен быть код с контейнером для рисования.
        //Класс MyFigure будет его наследовать и прикрепляться к окну.
        pack();
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

С помощью чего мне вообще можно что-то нарисовать и как лучше это добавить? Гугл не помог. Пока вот так это выглядит:

[image: programm]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JFrame**, как и множество других элементов таких как **JPanel** или **JButton**, наследуют класс [Component](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) имеющий метод [paint(Graphics g)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#paint(java.awt.Graphics)).
Переопределив этот метод в вашем классе, расширяющем сам JFrame или любой другой компонент, можно вмешаться в рисование этого компонента. При следующей перерисовке компонентов, например при масштабировании окна, будет обработан и ваш код.

Например:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test extends JFrame
{
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {new Test();}

    public Test()
    {
        super("Test");
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setSize(800, 600);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

В вашем случае, после нажатия кнопки, следует в какой-либо переменной хранить информацию о текущей фигуре, которую следует нарисовать. А в теле `paint`, в зависимости от текущего значения этой переменной, рисовать ту или иную фигуру по примеру выше.

Comment: через какой контейнер лучше это сделать? т.е. у меня есть HorizontalBox для кнопок, мне нужно еще добавить пространство для рисования фигур, а потом склеить это все вместе через какой-то вертикальный контейнер.

Comment: @mcstarioni я реализовывал подобное используя JPanel в качестве холста. Только вам понадобится настроить её(панели) размеры, так как иначе она добавится в свернутом до минимального размера и рисунка на ней вы не увидите.

Answer (score 1):

Например так.

```
Graphics2D g2d= (Graphics2D) super.getGraphics();
g2d.drawLine();
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?